# How to make a unique random number generator?

Tags: java

This code is obviously a random number generator, but how do i get it to be unique in the simplest way possible?

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Scramble {

public static void main(String[] args) {

            for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
            {

            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int n = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);

            System.out.println("Random number is " +n);
            }

      }

}
```

Comment: You need to understand that 'unique' and 'random' are mutually contradictory. The more numbers in the sequence you collect, the easier it becomes to predict the next one, so the sequence is far from 'random'.

Answer (score 6):

For this small number of possible values:

1. Generate a list of all possible values
2. Shuffle it
3. Return the next item in each step

Comment: when you say shuffle it? you mean collections.shuffle? i cannot use this as it is too advanced.

Comment: There isn't really any simpler solution, actually.

Comment: This isn't very practical when you have a random number that can go up to 1000000, but you want 5 unique numbers.

Comment: brice, hence the restriction in the very first line of my answer. Note also that the question didn't ask for five out of a million numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Does maximal-length [LFSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register) (e.g., [PRBS](http://www.altera.com.my/support/kdb/solutions/rd02142013_406.html) sequences) fits?

For instance, the PRBS31 sequence (x<sup>31</sup>+x<sup>28</sup>+1) is guaranteed to generate every 31-bit integer (except 0) only once in a cycle (which is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 bits long)

It is fairly easy to implement, too:

```
public int prbs31(int state) {
    int feedback = ((state >> 30) ^ (state >> 27)) & 1;
    return ((state << 1) | feedback) & 0xffffffff;
}
```

You start with some (non-zero!) integer, and call `prbs31` successively - passing the previous result back in. (it's a feedback register!)

PRBS31 generates very good statistically-random bit patterns (which is not to be confused with [truly random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#.22True.22_random_numbers_vs._pseudorandom_numbers) bit patterns)

However, keep in mind that adjacent values will be very similar - the method suggested above does a one-bit sliding-window over the PRBS sequence, meaning every adjacent values have 30-bits in common (though in different places)

But we can advance the register 31 steps each time, like so:

```
// initial seed, doesn't really matter which value you use
// as long as it's not zero (remember that the sequence goes over
// all the possible 31-bits values anyway)
private static final int SEED = 0x55555555;

private int state = SEED;

public int nextInt() throws SequenceCycleException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 31; ++i) {
        state = prbs31(state);
        if (state == SEED) {
            throw new SequenceCycleException();
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

This would generate a randomly-seeming sequence of integers that is (2<sup>31</sup>-1)/31 long

**DISCLAIMER:** naive usage of a single LFSR is highly predictable. In this case, knowing **one** value gives knowledge of **all** future values - which makes this method good for simulations (such as games) but also **very bad for anything with cryptographic or secret significance!**

Personally, I use this method to generate unique IDs for objects that are used as keys in a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way possible is to use clock arithmetic.
If you add by a number which is not a factor of 10 e.g. a prime (and the difference is not factor as well) you will get every possible value in a random walk. It not very random, but it is very simple.

e.g. say you pick 3 for 10 values.

```
3, 6, 9, 2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 7, 0
```

Comment: Is this random in any useful way?

Comment: When you only need a basic pseudo random such as walking bins of a hash map. (if you don't use a list) The beneifit is you don't need to retain any data structure or state other than the point you are looking at e.g. the hash.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a random number, store it in an `Array`/`HashMap`/Whatever and return it. Then you just have to check each time if the new number is already in your saved old ones. 
Not very efficient but easy.

Comment: Use List/Map/WhateverInterface instead of Array/HashMap/WhateverImplementation.

Answer (score -2):

This is the code sample for random number(integer) generation. Being we know that `Math.random()` always returns double type value. So , I have converted it into int.

```
class RNumber{
    public static void main(String str[]){
        int countNum=100;   
        for(int i=0;i<countNum;i++){
            System.out.println("Random Unique values="+(int)(Math.random()*100));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope, it will help you.

Comment: This doesn't help at all in selecting unique elements.

Comment: When you only need a basic pseudo random such as walking bins of a hash map. (if you don't use a list)

Comment: Sorry, I thought this questionw as for my answer. :P